# What is the Amillennial view of the ‘Times of the Gentiles’?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-luke, prophecy, gentile, amillennialism

Exactly when are the ‘Times of the Gentiles’ according to the Amillennial prophetic viewpoint?

> “There will be great distress upon the earth and wrath against this
>   people. They will fall by the edge of the sword and be led captive
>   among all nations, and Jerusalem will be trampled underfoot by the
>   Gentiles, until the **times of the Gentiles** are fulfilled.” (Luke
>   21:23-24)

I am looking for precise start and finish dates. What events mark those dates?  Also, a brief summary of the Amillennial thinking concerning this prophecy would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There  does not seem to be one view.   It is taken either as having a “temporal” significance or an “eschatological” one by Amillenials.

> **The Non-Millenarian View** [1]
>
> This takes us to the third point, and that is the meaning of the
>   phrase “until the full number of the Gentiles has come in” (v. 25).
>   Most commentators agree that Paul’s use of “until” (achri) has
>   **temporal** significance and is intended to mark that period of time when Israel’s hardening ends and her fullness and acceptance
>   begins.[53] Others, however, such as **O. Palmer Robertson**, insist
>   that the term has an **eschatological** significance and is indicative
>   of a condition that continues until the end.[54] The key here is
>   Paul’s phrase “the full number of the Gentiles.” According to
>   **Anthony Hoekema**, “The fullness here . . . must be understood in an eschatological way: the full number of Gentiles God intends to save.
>   When that number of Gentiles has been gathered in, it will be the end
>   of the age.”[55] Based on this interpretation, when the full number of
>   elect believers among the Gentiles has come in, then Israel’s hardness
>   will be removed, and Israel will attain the promised fullness and
>   acceptance shortly before the return of Jesus Christ. This
>   interpretation also comports with Jesus’s words that after God’s
>   judgment falls on Israel and her people are scattered among the
>   nations, “Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles until the
>   times of the Gentiles are fulfilled” (Luke 21:24). Once the times of
>   the Gentiles are fulfilled, God will remove Israel’s present hardness
>   of heart, and the nation will at long last return to her Messiah.

[1] “A case for Amilennialism”, © 2003, 2013 by Kim Riddlebarger Published by Baker Books a division of Baker Publishing Group P.O. Box 6287, Grand Rapids, MI 49516-6287 www.bakerbooks.com

http://a.co/20aOOub

Comment: The excerpt from Riddlebarger is useful. But can you summarize the 2 Amillenial views of the 'times of the Gentiles' in simple language please.

Comment: The summary is my first sentence.

Comment: I would like to note that the great multitude is from all nations, kindreds, people, and tongues. They come out of the great tribulation (Rev 7:9,14).

Comment: @AlanFuller  Agreed.   What is the significance of that to you?

Comment: IMO, in this life, we have tribulation (John16:33). The time of the Gentiles is symbolic of that. This is an interpretation of idealism.